# передать переменную с button

Tags: c#

Подскажите как в c# передать с обработчика button передать переменную в другой button.
Суть такая что при нажатие на кнопку я выбираю путь папки, затем сохраняю в переменную, как мне потом вызвать эту переменную уже в другом button ?

Comment: Объявите переменную как поле класса

Comment: `WPF` или `WinForms`?

Answer (score 5):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string fileName;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileName = @"d:\test.txt";
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(fileName);
    }
}
```

Прочтите [Область видимости (контекст) переменных](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.18.php)

Comment: Добавьте класс формы что ли, чтобы сразу было видно, как это в классе должно быть представлено